# Javascript function: Uncaught ReferenceError: potDeposit is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand a syntax issue may cause this, but I haven't found any syntax issues in my code.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="type/javascript">
        function potDeposit(id) {
            var depo = document.getElementById('deposit' + id);
            jQuery.get("ajax/potdeposit.php?id=" + id + "&amount=" + depo.value, function(data) {
                depo.value = '';
                if(data == '1') {
                    document.getElementById('error' + id).innerHTML = 'Insufficient Funds!';
                }else if(data == '2') {
                    document.getElementById('error' + id).innerHTML = 'Your account has been locked!';
                }else if(data == '3') {
                    document.getElementById('error' + id).innerHTML = 'Server Error! Pot doesn\'t exist.';
                }else if(data == '4') {
                    document.getElementById('error' + id).innerHTML = 'twarks.';
                }
                refreshPots();
            });
        }

        function refreshPots() {

        }
    </script>
```

Error from both Firebug & Chrome: `Uncaught ReferenceError: potDeposit is not defined`

Comment: Have you tried to invoke potDeposit before it has been declared? Also you have an internal variable called potdeposit which is also the name of the method name (With exception to the capital D).  This is quite confusing.

Comment: `<script type="type/javascript">` should be `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: The code I posted is in the head part of the document. It's invoked from a onClick in the body, of a input-button. I also tried calling it from the console, no change. I changed the variable name in my code, will update the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To declared javascript script, correct type is : `text/javascript`. You declared your script with `type/javascript`.  It should have been this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

instead of:

```
<script type="type/javascript">
```

Comment: Or, you can also just do `<script>` with no type and it will be javascript automatically.

Comment: Correct. It depend to DOCTYPE chose.